# Problemas con mi interfaz de array

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema construyendo una interfaz para manipular de varias maneras un array conteniendo una lista de números desordenados, esta es mi clase main, aquí creo el array y llamo a los métodos en las otras clases para usarlos:

```
public class Main {
    
    private static String arrayToString (int [] a) {
    
    final StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder ("{");
  
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (k > 0) {
        r.append (",");
        }
        r.append (a[k]);
    }
  
    r.append ("}");   
  
    return r.toString ();
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
    final Array a = new Array1 (new int [] {1,5,3,6,2,4});

    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (2,4))); // {3,6,2}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (-3,3))); // {1,5,3,6}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (3,7))); // {6, 2, 4}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (-5,-2))); // {}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (2,2))); // {3}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.subarray (6,6))); // {}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.todosMenos (2,4))); // {1,5,4}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.todosMenos(-3,3))); // {2,4}
    System.out.println (arrayToString (a.todosMenos(3,7))); // {1,5,3}

    }

}
```

Los comentarios que se encuentran al lado de las distintas llamadas a los métodos son lo que DEBERÍA de mostrarse cuando ejecuto el programa, esta es mi interfaz, donde creo los prototipos de los métodos:

```
public interface Array {
    int [] subarray (int a, int b);
    int [] todosMenos (int a, int b);
}
```

Y aquí esta la clase donde creo los métodos ya finalizados:

```
public class Array1 implements Array {
/* La clausula implements en este caso integra la interfaz del archivo Array.java, permitiendo integrar código a los prototipos */

    private final int [] array;
    
    public Array1 (int [] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    @Override
    public int [] subarray (int a, int b) {
        
        if (b < a || b < 0 || a >= array.length) {
            return new int [0];
        }

        if (a < 0) {
            a = 0;
        }
        
        if (b >= array.length) {
            b = array.length - 1;
        }
        
        final int [] r = new int [b - a + 1];
        
        for (int k = 0; k < r.length; k++) {
            r[k] = array[a + k];
        }
        
        return r;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int [] todosMenos (int a, int b) {
        
        if (b < a || b < 0 || a >= array.length) {
            final int [] r = new int [array.length];      
            for (int k = 0; k < r.length; k++) {
                r[k] = array[k];
            }
            return r;
        }
        
        if (a < 0) {
            a = 0;
        }
        
        if (b >= array.length) {
            b = array.length - 1;
        }
        
        final int [] r = new int [array.length - 1 - b + a];
        
        for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
            r[k] = array[a + k];
        }
        
        for (int k = a; k < r.length; k++) {
            r[k] = array[b - a + k + 1];
        }
        
        return r;
    }
}
```

Bien, ahora el problema, que tiene que ver con el método todosMenos. Se supone que el método subarray deberá devolver un array conteniendo una parte del array inicial. Por ejemplo, si el
array inicial es {1,5,3,6,2,4}, subarray(2,4) devolverá {3,6,2}, es decir, los elementos desde
el 2 hasta el 4, ambos inclusive. Si el parámetro b es menor que a, o si b es menor que cero, o si a es mayor o igual que el tamaño del array, este método devolverá un array de cero elementos. Si a es negativo, se hará lo mismo que si fuese cero, y si b es mayor o igual que el tamaño del array, se hará lo mismo que si fuese uno menos que el tamaño del array.

El método todosMenos deberá devolver todos los elementos del array EXCEPTO los que devolvería el método subarray, el problema es que, al ejecutar el código, este es mi resultado:

```
{3,6,2}
{1,5,3,6}
{6,2,4}
{}
{3}
{}
{3,6,4}
{2,4}
{6,2,4}
```

No tengo ni idea de como solucionar el método todosMenos, y es con lo que necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado estudiando tu código y haciendo algunas pruebas y creo que el problema está únicamente aquí

```
for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
    r[k] = array[a + k];
}
```

Si no he entendido mal, lo que se pretende es copiar las posiciones desde la 0 hasta la a del array original a la copia r, es decir

```
r[0] = array[0];   // k = 0
r[1] = array[1];   // k = 1
...
r[a - 1] = array[a - 1];  // k = a - 1
```

¿Ves que el indice empleado en ambos arrays es siempre igual?
Si sustituyes el bucle que te he señalado por este de abajo creo que debería funcionar

```
for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
     r[k] = array[k];
}
```

Las operaciones de indexado del segundo bucle pueden resultar algo confusas, pero creo que están bien. Haciendo el cambio sugerido, se obtiene la salida que esperas

```
{3,6,2}
{1,5,3,6}
{6,2,4}
{}
{3}
{}
{1,5,4}
{2,4}
{1,5,3}
```